# Method to prevent web caching throwing exception ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, http

I am trying to stop the caching of web pages using the following snippets in the ASP.NET however its not working and showing following error to me,

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-store";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.Expires = -1;
```

Following is the exception i am getting,

> **Exception Details:**
>   System.ArgumentException: Property
>   value for CacheControl is not valid.
>   Value=no-store.

Reading at the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524721%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) it looks "no-store" is valid value but still there is this error. Can some one please help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you've tried "No-store" (capital N) as per the docs?

Comment: This is a useful article as well: http://dotnetperls.com/cache-aspnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

That help page looks like it is an asp reference page, not an asp.net reference page.

The page you want is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cachecontrol.aspx which suggests that the valid values are those that match the httpcacheability enum. See the following page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability.aspx

In particular the value you want is, I would guess, NoCache. Though you'd have to read the help to make sure that is definitely the one you want.